# Cannot Set and get Cookie in .net core 2.0 API

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-2.0

I have create an API using .Net Core 2.0
In One on of the controller I am trying to set a cookie in one action and try to get it in another action. But I get null when I am debugging it.

The code is below:

```
public IActionResult Get()
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append("Test","dasdasdasdasd",new CookieOptions {
            Expires=DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)
        });
        return Ok();
    }

    // GET: api/Model/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var z = Request.Cookies["Test"];
        return Ok();
    }
```

in the second action I see z is null when I stop there by a break point.

Is there anything I am missing to set and get cookie?
A help would be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask how are you making the request?

Comment: @junkangli,  I am making 2 seperate ajax call from browser. What I think the browser should store the cookie and send it when another call is made.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working. One thing I could think of is when you retrieve the cookie you need to provide `Id`. Otherwise, it will call the create action method again.

### Index.cshtml

```
<button id="btn-create" type="button">Create Cookie</button>
<button id="btn-retrieve" type="button">Retrieve Cookie</button>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#btn-create').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("Get", "Values")',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            });

            $('#btn-retrieve').click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '@Url.Action("Get", "Values", new {id = 123})',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
}
```

### ValuesController.cs

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Values")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append("Test", "dasdasdasdasd", new CookieOptions
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)
        });
        return Ok();
    }

    // GET: api/Model/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var z = Request.Cookies["Test"];
        return Ok(z);
    }
}
```

Comment: I provided the Id,  still the cookie is null, another point , the client is running on different url . I am running 2 project one is the api and another is the client who calls the api.

Do I need to make any configuration change in StartUp.CS  or anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my mistake. I did not send the request properly 
In the request I had to set the

xhrFields:{WithCredentials:true}

actually the cookie was not sent back to server as I didn't set it. when I add this property to ajax request, then it finds the cookie